# How to scroll background in games?

Tags: android, background, scroll, game-loop

I have some basic programming skills but Im new in game programming. Know that every game needs a game loop, something like `while (true) { //do things }` in separate thread. But i wonder how is a scrollabe background (2D) used to be realized (when pressing arrow, main character is in the middle of screen, but background and things are moving). How could a simplest example of code for android platform looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for starting Android game development would be a game engine. Game engines make core features of games simple to use. Personally I recommend and use [LibGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/index.html). LibGDX provides easy to use *cameras* that can be moved through a world.

To answer your question, create a world and a player class in LibGDX. Each frame you could update the camera's world position to match the player's world position.